# Beginner Question why can I do str(number) and not str(letter)

Tags: python-3.x, string

As the title says, I dont understand why letters without quotes doesn't convert into a string while using the str() method.

```
f = str(ab)
print(type(ab))
print(type(f))
```

returns a NameError: name 'ab' is not defined.

So I have to write it as 'ab'.

When using numbers, I do not need the quotes, like

```
f = str(10)
print(type(10))
print(type(f))
```

returns

<class 'int'>

<class 'str'>

Is it because letters doesnt belong to a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because variables are any combination of letters/numbers and symbols, such as Hello_There. Therefore as far as Python is concerned **ab** is a variable name, not a string. To tell Python its a string you have to put quote marks around it.

Comment: thanks Kosh, I just thought it could kind of being "forced" with the str() method to be a string.

Comment: No, because ab might in fact be a variable which itself contains string. Such as ab="hello there' f=str(ab), print (f) - Output 'hello there', not 'ab' Maybe you change ab as part of a loop for instance.